# getting run time error when inserting a new columns by inputbox

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

getting run time error 1004 application defined or object defined error when i am run this vba

```
Sub InsertColumns()
    Dim ColumnNumber As String
    Dim NumColumns As Long

    ' Get column letter from user
    ColumnNumber = InputBox("Enter the column letter where you want to insert a new column:")

    ' Remove space character from column letter
    ColumnNumber = Trim(ColumnNumber)

    ' Convert column letter to column number
    ColumnNumber = Range(ColumnNumber & "1").Column

    ' Get number of columns to insert from user
    NumColumns = InputBox("Enter the number of columns to insert:")

    ' Insert columns
    Columns(ColumnNumber).Resize(NumColumns).EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is from the the first part (`Columns(ColumnNumber)`) of the last statement. You have defined `ColumnNumber` as a string. But `Columns` is expecting an index, meaning a number (integer, long, etc).

You should either:

- cast `ColumnNumber` as an integer: `Int(ColumnNumber)`
- or define an integer variable and assign `ColumnNumber` to it

Your code will be like the below if you do the casting:

```
Sub InsertColumns()
    Dim ColumnNumber As String
    Dim NumColumns As Long

    ' Get column letter from user
    ColumnNumber = InputBox("Enter the column letter where you want to insert a new column:")

    ' Remove space character from column letter
    ColumnNumber = Trim(ColumnNumber)

    ' Convert column letter to column number
    ColumnNumber = Range(ColumnNumber & "1").Column

    ' Get number of columns to insert from user
    NumColumns = InputBox("Enter the number of columns to insert:")

    ' Insert columns
    Columns(Int(ColumnNumber)).Resize(NumColumns).EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Reddy Lutonadio

Comment: one more small query it's inserting only one column only when i enter number 3 in NumColumns Inputbox

Comment: @visshnu That's normal as you are inserting only one column `EntireColumn.Insert`; Your `Resize` is doing nothing here. Use a loop and remove `Resize` as the following: `    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To NumColumns
    Columns(Int(ColumnNumber)).EntireColumn.Insert shift:=xlToRight, copyorigin:=xlFormatFromLeftOrAbove
    Next i`

Comment: Once again thank you so much for your help @Reddy Lutonadio